# App-specific passwords not working anymore under Android 5

Tags: google-account, password-protection

I am using multi-factor authentication for all my Google accounts.

I am pretty sure that I once used app-specific passwords on my Android (that time version 4 of Android) devices to authenticate.

Yesterday I reset my device and also the app-specific passwords I created earlier. I recreated new app-specific passwords.

Then, after having restarted my freshly reset Android device I tried to add one of my Google account after the other. As part of that I am, for each single account, first asked for my mail address and password. But, for whatever reason the app-specific passwords are just not accepted. Once entered I am just prompted again and asked for my password. Fascinatingly Google seems to recognize that the password is correct, because if I enter a wrong one on purpose I really get an error saying that the password is wrong.

Entering my "main" Google password works and leads me to a UI then asking for my Google Authenticator code.

Are app-specific passwords no longer support for adding my accounts on Android or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 I support your case. I haven't tested on a non-Google app but I can confirm  that Google requires the actual password and not app-specific password for signing-in on Android. Incidentally, I was also on Lollipop.